# nodejs routing strange behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a view call register.jade

```
extend layout

block content
    h1 Register
    p Please register using the form below
    form(method='post',action='users/register',enctype='multiple/form-data')
        .form-group
            label Name
            input.form-control(name='name',type='text',placeholder='name')
        .form-group
            label Email
            input.form-control(name='email',type='text',placeholder='Enter Email')
        .form-group
            label Username
            input.form-control(name='username',type='text',placeholder='Usernama')
        .form-group
            label Password
            input.form-control(name='password',type='text',placeholder='Enter Password')
        .form-group
            label Confirm Password
            input.form-control(name='password2',type='text',placeholder='Confirm Password')
        .form-group
            label Profile Image
            input.form-control(name='profileimage',type='file')
        input.btn.btn-default(name='submit',type='submit',value='Register')
```

When I click the submit it goes to 
http://localhost:3000/users/users/register and it says Not found.

Why does that happen? In my user.js I have this

```
router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('register',{
    'title':'Register'
  });
});

router.post('/register',function(req,res,next){

});
```

Comment: What is the original URL where this form renders? Looks like it is `http://localhost:3000/users/` and therefore the relative URL appends to it. If that is the case, you should only have `register` in your action url, and not `users/register`, or make it relative to the root `/users/register`.

Comment: @show-me-the-code shit it worked! so hard to debug nodejs. Thanks for the help!